# Error resolving method in View Model class in Android

Tags: java, android, api, android-recyclerview, android-viewmodel

I am new to Android Devlopement and I was trying to fetch a list of earthquakes from a website using API call and displaying them on the screen using Recycler view. I am trying to incorporate the ViewModel into my app now so that multiple API calls are not made when the screen is rotated but I don't understand why I am getting the error: `Cannot resolve method 'getEarthquakes' in ViewModel` Here are my MainActivity(EarthquakeActivity) and ViewModel(MyModel) class implementations in Java.

EarthquakeActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.earthquake;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewModel mViewModel;
    private ViewModelProvider mViewModelProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.earthquake_activity);
        mViewModelProvider = new ViewModelProvider(this);
        mViewModel = mViewModelProvider.get(MyModel.class);
        // find a reference to the {@link RecyclerView} in the layout
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.earthquakes);
        // fetch the list of earthquakes
        ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = mViewModel.getEarthquakes();// error on this line
        // create adapter passing in the earthquake data
        EarthquakeAdapter earthquakeAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(EarthquakeActivity.this,earthquakes);

        // attach the adapter to the recyclerView to populate the items
        recyclerView.setAdapter(earthquakeAdapter);

        // set the layout manager to position the items
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(EarthquakeActivity.this));
        // click listener for when an item is clicked
        earthquakeAdapter.setClickListener((view, position) -> searchWeb(earthquakes.get(position).getUrl()));

    }

    private void searchWeb (String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY,url);
        if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

and  MyModel.java

```
package com.example.android.earthquake;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MyModel extends ViewModel {
    private ArrayList<Earthquake> mEarthquakes;

    public ArrayList<Earthquake> getEarthquakes() {
        // perform the network request on separate thread
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // create array list of earthquakes
                mEarthquakes = QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&eventtype=earthquake&orderby=time&minmag=6&limit=10");
            }
        });
        executorService.shutdown();
        return mEarthquakes;
    }

}
```

Even writing this much of ViewModel was so hard for me since almost all the tutorials out there use Kotlin and I found out that Loaders are deprecated. Also, If possible, can someone also tell me how can I update the UI with latest data of earthquakes if the API changes when new earthquakes occur without having to restart the app? I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a lot of gaps here.

Let us start with your EarthquakeActivity, here the type of your mViewModel is ViewModel, it should be MyModel and since ViewModel class does not have getEarthquakes() method in it, you are getting that error.

At line, ArrayList earthquakes = mViewModel.getEarthquakes();
You are asking your viewmodel to provide you the list and the network call is gonna take some time and it is also asynchronous so you will receive an empty list.

To fix this, you need to use MutableLiveData<ArrayList> in your viewmodel and you need to observe it in your activity so that you can get the callback when you update this value after receiving data from the network call, I will also suggest you use retrofit for the network call.

So your final code will look something like this,

EarthquakeActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyModel mViewModel;
    private ViewModelProvider mViewModelProvider;
    
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.earthquake_activity);
        
        //init viewmodel
        mViewModelProvider = new ViewModelProvider(this);
        mViewModel = mViewModelProvider.get(MyModel.class);
        
        // find a reference to the {@link RecyclerView} in the layout
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.earthquakes);
        
        // fetch and observer the list of earthquakes
        mViewModel.getEarthquakes().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<Earthquake>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes) {
                //setup recycler view with this data, this will work even if you rotate the device
                setUpRecyclerView(earthquakes);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView(ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes) {
        // create adapter passing in the earthquake data
        EarthquakeAdapter earthquakeAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(EarthquakeActivity.this,earthquakes);
        // attach the adapter to the recyclerView to populate the items
        recyclerView.setAdapter(earthquakeAdapter);
        // set the layout manager to position the items
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(EarthquakeActivity.this));
        // click listener for when an item is clicked
        earthquakeAdapter.setClickListener((view, position) -> searchWeb(earthquakes.get(position).getUrl()));
    }

    private void searchWeb (String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY,url);
        if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

And your MyModel.java

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MyModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Earthquake>> mEarthquakesLiveData;

    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Earthquake>> getEarthquakes() {
        // perform the network request on separate thread
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // create array list of earthquakes
                mEarthquakesLiveData.setValue(QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&eventtype=earthquake&orderby=time&minmag=6&limit=10"));
            }
        });
        executorService.shutdown();
        return mEarthquakesLiveData;
    }

}
```

I hope this will help you, feel free to upvote. Good day man!!